# What's the correct way to process a file with multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, perl

I'm trying to process a file about 4g bytes in size. I want it to be multi-threaded, so I will use seek to adjust the file handler.

First I will determine where to break the file, once done I will have an array of seek points.

Then in each thread I reopen the file for reading, e.g `open my $fh2, '<input' or die $!;`

Which seems stupid.

Is there a better solution? The file is too big I cannot load any part of into memory directly.

Comment: You need to rethink what you're doing - I/O parallellizes really poorly. Having four threads trying to read different parts of the same file will likely be a lot slower than just using one thread. The best solution is having one thread reading chunks which it passes to other threads for processing.

Comment: @gustafc I think the part the processes each line is slow, but since I can't preload the whole file .. so multithread reading of file seems like a solution

Comment: @gustafc Ah I seem to get it

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl [threads](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html). So you will open file only once but process in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Create a boss-worker model, the 'boss' process will read the data & pass it to 'workers'.